# After or Afterwards?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality

> I shall make my final decision **after/afterwards** I have discussed the problem with my family.

As I found out, it means the same thing, but I have this sentence which confuses me.
Can you help me understand the difference between them?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Could you cite where you found out that they mean the same thing? Could you tell us if you think "after" or "afterwards" is more appropriate?

Comment: They only mean the same thing if they are the same part of speech, but that is the difference which an answer might address.

Comment: You would have to say "I shall discuss it with my family and make my decision afterwards".

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes they are interchangeable, but not always. In your example, *after* is correct but *afterwards* is not.

Short technical answer – both are adverbs, but *after* can also be used as a preposition. *After* as a preposition is used to point the sentence to another place or time. As a preposition, *after* can come at the beginning of a sentence, at the end of a sentence, or between two clauses (like in your example). An adverb is used to qualify a verb or word group, often on the basis of time or space. It will usually come before a verb or word group, or at the beginning or end of a sentence. In your example *afterwards* is not clearly attached to the verb in either clause.

http://www.differencebetween.net/language/difference-between-after-and-afterward/